# Find width and height of a data set using eigenvectors?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a box represented by a set of points. I have found eigen vectors of those data set using principal component analysis. Is there a way I can measure the width(horizontal span) and height(vertical span) of the data sets using eigenvectors.

Comment: Why would you want to compute the span using eigenvectors? Is it not faster (and much more straightforward) to iterate through all your data points with comparisons to compute the bounding box?

Comment: Points are not in a plane. They are in 3d space. I want to calculate span in the direction of all three eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your eigenvectors be $v_j$ for $i=1,2,3$. Let's assume that they are normalized so that $v_j\cdot v_j = 1$, etc. You just need to iterate through all your points and determine the projection along the vectors, and store the min and max values for each eigenvector. In code,

```
maxdist[3] = {-INFINITY, -INFINITY, -INFINITY}
mindist[3] = {+INFINITY, +INFINITY, +INFINITY}
for each point p[i], i = 1,...,N
    for each eigenvector v[j], j = 1,2,3
        d = dot_product(v[j], p[i])
        maxdist[j] = max(d,maxdist[j])
        mindist[j] = min(d,mindist[j])
```

Then the width for the first eigenvector is `maxdist[1] - mindist[1]` and so on.

Comment: So i should convert the vectors to unit vectors??? i.e normalize

Comment: @manjunathreddya04: yes

Comment: But any idea which corresponding eigenvector represents width, height and breadth?.